# Why does networkx say my directed graph is disconnected when finding diameter?

Tags: python, networkx, network-analysis

I'm crawling slideshare.net graph, starting at my node and following all the users in BFS, until the number of visited nodes is 1000.
I perform BFS in the following way:

```
from urllib.request import urlopen
from collections import deque
import sys
import json
import codecs
import csv
import io
import hashlib
import time
import xml.etree.ElementTree as etree
queue = deque(["himanshutyagi11"])
while len_visitedset < 1ooo:
        vertex = queue.pop()
        if vertex in visited:
            continue
        visited.add(vertex)
        length_visited = len(visited)
        print(vertex,length_visited)
        crawl(vertex)
```

crawl() is a function in which I make the slideshare api query as explained [here](http://www.slideshare.net/developers/documentation#get_user_contacts)  create the query payload by using my shared_secret and api_key ( given at the time for api registration), send the query and parse the XML response stored in variable 'response'. After parsing, I add the contacts of the present node in the queue.

```
request_timestamp = int(time.time())
request_hash_string = shared_secret+str(request_timestamp)
request_hash_value = hashlib.sha1(request_hash_string.encode('utf-8')).hexdigest()
request_url = 'https://www.slideshare.net/api/2/get_user_contacts?username_for='+username+'&api_key='+api_key+'&hash='+request_hash_value+'&ts='+str(request_timestamp)
response = etree.parse(urlopen(request_url)).getroot()
# Append all the adjacent nodes of this user to the queue.
    for child in response:
        friend_name = child[0].text
        queue.appendleft(friend_name)
edge_file = open('non_anonymized.csv','a')
    for child in response:
        f_name = child[0].text                              # Name of friend is stored in variable 'f_name'
        edge_file.write(username+','+f_name+'\n')          # username is the name of user currently being crawled
    edge_file.close()
```

While crawling I also create a edgelist.csv file, that contains all the edges in the graph. This file seems to be fine.
Also other functions such as degree(), in_degree(), average_clustering() seem to be working fine.

Then I use networkx to create a graph, which has 1000 nodes. But if I try to find diameter of this graph using following function:

```
diameter = nx.diameter(graph)
```

With above code, I am not able to find the diameter of my graph, this doe not return anything and my program is stuck at this line. Any insights to what might be happening ?
Mine is a connected graph. I'm converting it to an undirected one using `to_undirected()` function. I tired running it with the directed graph, and I got the following error
`networkx.exception.NetworkXError: Graph not connected: infinite path length`

My question is how can it be disconnected since I am using BFS to crawl.

> Python 3.4
>   Networkx 1.9.1

Comment: If your program is stuck at this line, then it hasn't completed yet -- so of course it hasn't returned anything.  Please try checking the integrity of your graph (number of nodes, connectivity, etc.).  Also, try a smaller graph (say, 10 nodes) and work your way up.  This will show whether it's a problem with *any* graph, or just with a large graph.

Comment: I don't exactly follow you on the check connectivity part. Can you elaborate on this one ?

Comment: Can you check that your graph is connected -- that each node is connected to another, and that there is a path from one node to each of the others?  I'm not familiar with Networkx (I use TrustedAnalytics and Titan), so I'm not sure what query capabilities you have.

Comment: That's why I asked you to use a query on the graph.  The network exception says that your graph is *not* connected.  Can you please post according to http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve -- give us a complete and minimal example to reproduce the problem?  Can you print out the graph structure, such as an edge list?  I'm suspicious about the graph creation.  I've been through enough of these in my own code.

Comment: Now it is how can it be disconnected if I'm using BFS. I have updated the question with my BFS method

Comment: Hey - I edited the title of the question to make it easier for people with similar questions to find.  Please double check that you're happy with it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The source code for diameter is [here](https://networkx.github.io/documentation/latest/_modules/networkx/algorithms/distance_measures.html#diameter).  It relies on `eccentricity` which is the function just above that in the source code.  `eccentricity` finds the shortest path from a node to all other nodes.  The error message you are getting comes from this part of the code:

```
if L != order:
    msg = "Graph not connected: infinite path length"
    raise networkx.NetworkXError(msg)
```

Here `L` is the number of nodes that were reachable from a given node and `order` is the number of nodes in the network.  `L != order` means that there are nodes not reachable from the given node.  In the case of an undirected network, this means the network is not connected.  However in your case you have a directed network.  For a directed network `L != order` means that the network is not "strongly-connected".  It could actually be weakly-connected, and yours presumably is.

So you've hit an error message that is not quite accurate.

For the directed network you've created, the diameter is infinite: if there is a node `u` which has no path to `v`, this means an infinite diameter.

Comment: Hey thanks for the detailed explanation. It cleared why the diameter was coming as infinite. But can you suggest any other way of finding diameter for a weakly connected graph ?

Answer (score 4):

I'm way late to the party, but have encountered the same problem and figure others may still encounter it.

Joel has explained the source of the problem. The diameter function relies on a net being strongly connected.

For a weakly connected graph one could use: `diameter = nx.diameter(net.to_undirected())`

Answer (score 4):

You cannot compute diameter for either 1) a weakly-connected directed graph or 2) a disconnected graph, but you might use the maximal shortest path like so:

```
diameter = max([max(j.values()) for (i,j) in nx.shortest_path_length(G)])
```

This finds the maximum distance of a list containing the shortest paths between any two nodes in G (computed with Dijkstra's algorithm), regardless of what component they may belong to.
Technically, diameter is infinite for disconnected graphs which is why NetworkX's built-in method does not work. The method above will find the largest diameter amongst all components within G, but is not the diameter of G itself.